# Расширение qss в классе наследнике qwidget

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator, qwidget, qss

У меня есть класс, наследник qwidget, с ui и описанной в нем таблице стилей. есть наследники этого класса в котором мне надо расширить эту таблицу, пробую задать в наследника таблицу стилей через setStyleSheet. Пробую проверить таблицу в созданном наследнике и она та, что я задаю в нем, но рисуется он так, будто активна только таблица родительского класса заданная в ui. Как мне расширять таблицы по мере наследования?

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно надо получить строку с QSS родителя потом приаттачить к ней строку с вашим новым QSS и сделать setStyleSheet().
Но на мой взгляд это плохой дизайн. 
Лучше вынести все QSS в отдельный файл и делать setStyleSheet() один раз при старте программы. При таком подходе вы можете изменять стили приложения даже не залезая в исходный код. 
В рамках этого вы сможете использовать наследование для таблиц стилей, так же как это работает с CSS. Просто почитайте побольше про селекторы.

Comment: До одного большого QSS пока далеко. Сейчас и правда делаю конкатинацией двух таблиц, но согласен что это такое себе. Хотелось чего то в духе именно addStyle()